# How to print on whole width of a dymo label?

Tags: java, printing, dymo

I'm trying to print a label on a Dymo Labelwriter 450 with a Java Application.
But I have a problem with the area on which it really print...

Here is what I get :

[image]

As you can see there is nothing printed on the right of the label... (It should be printed "Thingsplay")

And here is the code I'm using :

```
public class LabelWriter {

    private static final boolean printToPDF = false;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static final String PRINTERNAME = "DYMO LabelWriter";
    public static final String PDF_PRINTER = "Print to PDF";

    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pageFormat = printerJob.defaultPage();
    Paper paper = new Paper();

    public void printLabel(final String text) {

        final double widthPaper = (2.244 * 72);
        final double heightPaper = (1.254 * 72);

        paper.setSize(widthPaper, heightPaper);
        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, widthPaper, heightPaper);

        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
        pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

        PrintService[] printService = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

        for (int i = 0; i < printService.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(printService[i].getName());
            if ((printToPDF && printService[i].getName().contains(PDF_PRINTER)) || (!printToPDF && printService[i].getName().contains(PRINTERNAME))) {
                try {
                    printerJob.setPrintService(printService[i]);
                    printerJob.setPrintable(new CustomPrintable(widthPaper, heightPaper, text), pageFormat);
                    if (printerJob.printDialog()) {
                        printerJob.print();
                    }
                } catch (PrinterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first, when I installed the printer driver and went into the "print options" I saw that the available paper was set on "30252 Address" and I couldn't change that (I'm using 11354 Multi Purpose Label). But I saw on the internet that I had to change the default print options which I did :

[image: Available Paper]

[image: Default print options]

Despite all that when I print with the `printDialog()` option the paper format is set on "30886 CD Label" ... And even when I change the format here it still print as the image shown above :

[image]

Note that when I print on a PDF I have the whole text correctly printed.
I tried to change the margins using `paper.setImageableArea()` method but I still can't print on the right side of the label.

Comment: I *fear* that this question might be too specific (resulting in "no answers"), but kudos for trying to really have all relevant information in your question!